# Complex groupby operation using Pandas to capture a many to one scenario

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Below is a small sample of my  dataframe which is of millions of rows. It indicates Send_customers sending money to Pay_Customers.

```
      In [14]: df1
      Out[14]:
          Send_Customer         Pay_Customer
0       1000000000009548332  2000000000087113758
1       1000000000072327616  2000000000087113758
2       1000000000081537869  2000000000087113758
3       1000000000007725765  2000000000078800989
4       1000000000031950290  2000000000078800989
5       1000000000082570417  2000000000078800989
6       1000000000009548332  1000000000142041382
7       1000000000072327616  1000000000142041382
8       2000000000097181041  1000000000004033594
```

I need to store a count for those send_customers that are involved in a many to one scenario.

For instance , Pay_Customers 2000000000087113758,2000000000078800989,1000000000142041382 are receiving money from multiple send_customers. So , for all those Send_Customers sending money to them , the "count" value will be 1.

Send_Customers 1000000000009548332 and 1000000000072327616 are involved in 2 many to one scenarios with Pay_Customers  2000000000087113758 and 1000000000142041382 respectively , so there cumulative "count" should be 2.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
print(df1.groupby('Send_Customer')['Pay_Customer'].count())
```

Output:

```
Send_Customer
1000000000007725765    1
1000000000009548332    2
1000000000031950290    1
1000000000072327616    2
1000000000081537869    1
1000000000082570417    1
2000000000097181041    1
```

As per your comment, if you want to only keep the rows where the `count` is higher than `1` you can do this instead:

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Send_Customer')['Pay_Customer'].count().reset_index(name="count")
df1 = df1[df1['count'] > 1]
```

Output:

```
1  1000000000009548332      2
3  1000000000072327616      2
```

Comment: Hi. my dataframe has millions of rows. Above was just a small sample. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier.I only need to take the count of those Customers involved in a many to one scenario. So , in this sample no need to take a count for Send_customer 2000000000097181041 as its Pay_customer is not involved in a many to one scenario.